# sql mvc Calling SSIS packages by searching for a string

Tags: sql, model-view-controller, ssis

I have the user mentioning the filenames from the front end.
At the back end , I have a database , where I have a stored procedure in which I am calling SSIS packages based on the incoming filename.

The problem is I have a number of input files , 
So i don't think I should write
If(file name = x)
call the stored procedure that contains(x)

because there will be too many if-else statements , also I don't know how to count through all the packages.
Is there any other way?

Comment: `If filename == "a" then PackageA elseif filename == "b" then PackageB ... else PackageZ` Is this the type of relationship between file names and packages?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a master package that the stored procedure calls and passes the file name, and have a table that controls what package to call based on the file name. The Master package would use the table to look up the package name and invoke it.